# Prevent the inverse of values being used during an iteration in Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I'm given an array of n integers and a number k. I've found out whether there is a pair of elements in the array that sums to exactly k. For example, given the array [1, 3, 7] and k = 8, the answer is yes, but given k = 6 the answer is no.

My first attempt is to use the brute force approach. I have a decent algorithm that gets the job done not worrying about efficiency.

```
arr = [1,3,7]

for i in range(len(arr)):
    for a in range(len(arr)):
        if i != a:
            if arr[i] + arr[a] == 8:
                print('{} and {} is: yes'.format(arr[i], arr[a]))

            elif arr[i] + arr[a] == 6:
                print('{} and {} is: no'.format(arr[i], arr[a]))
```

This outputs the following:

```
1 and 7 is: yes
7 and 1 is: yes
```

Obviously I don't want the inverse case `arr[0] + arr[2] and arr[2] + arr[0]` displayed. I tried using array pop and del for `arr[i`] within the output loops.

How can I tell python to ignore the inverse case?

Comment: Is the list sorted? If so, there is an O(n) solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an excellent use case for a set. Remember, a + b == n <--> a == n-b.

Checking membership in a set is O(1). Thus, we can solve this with two iterations through our iterable. One to create the set, and one to check for our 'partner'. We can make sure to only return our pairs in the 'correct order' by making sure that our first item is smaller than the target // 2

```
def gen_pairs(iterable, target):
    iterable = set(iterable)
    for i in iterable:
        if target-i in iterable and i <= target // 2:
            yield i, target-i
```

Here's a brief example:

```
arr = [1,3,7,5]
print(list(gen_pairs(arr, 8)))
```

OUTPUT: `[(1, 7), (3, 5)]`

Note the following (deliberate) bug. Why does this happen? How would you fix this? (Hint - collections.Counter is your friend!)

```
arr2 = [4, 1, 7]
print(list(gen_pairs(arr2, 8)))
[(1, 7), (4, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change:

```
for a in range(len(arr)):
```

to

```
for a in range(i+1,len(arr)):
```

This will then only test cases when i < a so arr[0]+arr[2] will be found, but it won't try the inverse case.

A faster approach is to add each item into a set and look to see if 8-arr[i] is present in the set.  This will be O(n) instead of O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just ensure the second element always being later in the list than the first. Also, if you have a list, it is possible to loop over the elements, rather than their indices.

```
arr = [1,3,7]

for i, first in enumerate(arr):
    for second in arr[i+1:]:
        if first + second == 8:
            print('{} and {} is: yes'.format(first, second))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using 'any'?

```
a = [1,3,7]
if any(v+w == 8 and i != j for i,v in enumerate(a) for j,w in enumerate(a)):
    print "yes"
```